# Django-Tables2 with Checkbox Prefilled Value

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am trying to pre-render checked checkboxes using django-tables2 but cannot successfully do so.

This is my tables.py file.
`id` is the field I need to store as it's used to update the database, setting the `selected` field to true on a form submission. How can I get the `checked` parameter to work with this and properly reference the `selected` field?

```
class SomeTable(tables.Table):
    add = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor='id',checked='selected')

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ['name','add']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [Table.render_foo method](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods) which overrides the rendering if this column:

```
from django_tables2.utils import AttributeDict

class SomeTable(tables.Table):
    add = tables.CheckBoxColumn(empty_values=())

    def render_add(self, value, bound_column, record):
        default = {"type": "checkbox", "name": bound_column.name, "value": record.id}
        general = self.attrs.get("input")
        specific = self.attrs.get("td__input")
        attrs = AttributeDict(default, **(specific or general or {}))
        return mark_safe("<input %s/>" % attrs.as_html())

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ['name','add']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how would I customize this though for my case? I have the "id" field so it can be properly called and updated in views.py and the "selected" binary field which should be the flag if it's checked or not.

Comment: You will receive multiple instances of the add parameter for each selected item when you submit this form such as `?add=1&add=3`. Unmarked entries are not submitted.